# Access $vuetify in vue3 plugin

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a vue3 plugin that needs access to $vuetify for some theme related work.
I tried several things but can't make it work.

My plugin looks like this

```js
export const ColorPlugin: Plugin = {
    install: (app) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$color = function(this: InstanceType<DefineComponent>, key: string): string {
            let color = (this.$vuetify as any).theme.current.colors[key];

            // Do some work on the color

            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

I import the plugin like this

```js
export function registerPlugins (app: App) {
  loadFonts();
  app.use(vuetify).use(ColorPlugin);
}

...

const app = createApp(App);
registerPlugins(app);
app.mount('#app');
```

And I've got some components defined as

```js
<template>
  <div :style="wrapperStyle">
    <v-icon v-if="icon" :color="$color(color)">
      {{ icon }}
    </v-icon>
    <span v-if="label">
      {{ label }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance, PropType } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FSLabelWithIcon",
  props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: null
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: null
    },
    iconColor: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "primary"
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "secondary"
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    // only way I found to use the $color function declared in my plugin
    const globalProperties = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties;


    const contentStyle = {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      gap: "8px",
      backgroundColor: globalProperties.$color(props.backgroundColor)
    };

    return {
      icon: props.icon,
      label: props.label,
      color: props.iconColor,
      contentStyle
    };
  }
})
</script>
```

Now the issue I'm facing is that the $color call in the template works fine, but the one in the setup throws an error because this.$vuetify is undefined.

How can I access this.$vuetify in my plugin both from the template and the setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vuetify 3, the `$vuetify` global object was dropped in favor of composables. For theme-related data, use the [`useTheme`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/use-theme/) composable:

```
useTheme().current.colors[key]
```

Here is a [playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: It seems useTheme() can only be used during setup, not even in a function returned by the setup. So I cannot compute some variations of a color on the fly with my $color function. Is there a way to call a function using useTheme() from the component's template?

Comment: Typically, you would call `useTheme` during setup and store the returned value, which you can use in the template